Fronus Inverter Issue - PV Input Voltage Fluctuating, but Zero PV Input Watts and Amps
I'm seeking assistance with an issue I'm experiencing with my Fronus inverter. After two years of proper operation, I've noticed the following problem:

PV Input Voltage: 90V-220V (fluctuating according to sunlight)
PV Input Watts: 0
PV Input Amps: 0

My setup consists of:

10 x 24V solar panels
Fronus infeneon PV 7000 inverter
4 tubular batteries

Despite the fluctuating PV input voltage, the inverter is not detecting any power output from the solar panels. However, I've observed the following:

My batteries are charging, indicating that the PV current is present (I can see the charging current on my battery monitor)
The AC charging feature is turned off, and the batteries are charging solely through the PV current

I'm puzzled by the inverter's failure to detect PV input watts and amps despite the apparent flow of PV current.
I would appreciate any guidance or troubleshooting suggestions from the community to resolve this issue.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Have you tried contacting the manufacturer or the vendor? What does the product manual say?

@Muneeb : It's "Fronius" instead of "Fronus" (just in case someone else has a similar issue and searches for "Fronius")
